# How to install a bookmark in the Firefox menu?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I am trying to install [Stackoverflow microsummary](http://mozilla.doslash.org/so/) in Firefox. In one of the screenshot, we can see the bookmark being installed next to the 'Help' menu. How can you install a bookmark in the menu bar in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that link works fine, just install [this](http://sam.haslers.info/firefox-microsummaries.html), head over to your [recent activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/183100)  and bookmark it. Double click on the star.

For the name dropdown, select the microsummary feed.

[image]

[image]

And select the folder as Bookmarks toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking about putting the bookmark in the menu like it is shown in the 2nd screenshot. So you think it is not feasible?

Comment: @pascal it's not in the menu, it's just next to the menu in the screenshot. For this goto `View` menu -> `Toolbars` -> `Customize` -> Drag a flexible space next to `Help` menu and then drag the bookmarks toolbar next to the flexible space. Remove any existing bookmarks on the toolbar besides the microsummary and you're done. This is how it looks on mine after doing the steps http://i.imgur.com/0lnDc.png

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! But is it just me or you absolutely need to hover the mouse over the bookmark for the reputation to appear?

Comment: @Pascal - You're welcome! give it some time, it should reflect it automatically. Atleast that's what I remember when I had this before. Don't know if something's changed over time :)